# Generic "the" used in other places in a sentence, maybe not as a subject?

Tags: word-usage, articles, definite-article

I know "the" can be used to refer to a thing in general, which works like a noun in its plural form.

For examples,

(1) **The lion** is big and hunts other animals for food.

(2) The organization decides to put **the lion** on the list of endangered species.

(3) I want to understand **the lion** in detail.

---

**First question:**

The (2) and (3) are also generic use of "the", right?

**Second question:**

We can see the generic "the" used in subjects often.

And I am pretty sure the generic "the" can be used in other parts of a sentence like, maybe as the article of an object like (2) and (3) to refer to that thing in a general sense, or used in other parts of a sentence to give the noun after "the" a general tone.... yes, I think you understand what I mean.

But why do we seldom see the generic "the" used with objects (like (2) and (3)) or used in other parts of a sentence?

Comment: I wouldn't say it was uncommon to use _the_ before an animal's name to refer to its species in general.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, you're right. It's not uncommon. Do you think generic use of "the" is often used with subjects only? I think it can be used elsewhere, too. But it is seldom used that way. I am wondering whether it is because it can be confusing when "the" appears as a part of the object or elsewhere. For example, Humans need to take care of the lion. Without context, it is unclear whether it is the generic use of "the" because it can also mean "one specific lion." What do you think about this subject matter?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [Endangered species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endangered_species) contains quite a few instances of 'the [species]' being used as the object of a sentence.